# How can I have my app update every week with a new image and text?

Tags: android

All I need is to be able to change a picture and some text on a page in my app every week. The user can not change this only me. Everywhere I look it says something different. It says I need a server then somewhere else it says I need to make a sql database. I am new to android development and I am very confused any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You want for exemple update in every monday?

Comment: Yes every monday we would change the picture and the description.

Comment: Try Firebase. With Remote Config you can change link to image and text. And it's completely free. It's much easier than server, sql database or whatever https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/

Comment: Thank you so much this looks like it could work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in many ways. The simple way is by sending **FCM** message. Send image **URL** and **Text** from Firebase console. Then you can change the image and text without making database and server.

If you need more info about **FCM**, go through this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Answer (score 1):

You can implement above functionality with number of ways

```
1)You can use Push notification (GCM/FCM) and with use of notification you can update Image and text.
2)You can use JobScheduler and schedule for every day and call API by which you can get image and text details.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(yourdate); // yourdate is an object of type Date

int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); 

if(dayOfWeek==2){
   //Do stuff

}
```

Or you can do this:

```
if (Calendar.MONDAY == dayOfWeek) {
        //Do stuff
}
```

So this gets the current day of week and checks if is moday if yes do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what I need to to be able to change this stuff from outside the app.

Comment: outside the app you mean if app is closed?

Comment: Well i am making this app for an office I work at and they need to easily be able to change the image and text.

Comment: @JaidenRodriguez daily memes to keep coders in good mood? :D

Comment: @DimaRostopira Lol I wish :p

Answer (score -1):

If you have a cloud database, and is referring to the in the

```
if (Calendar.MONDAY == dayOfWeek) {
        //weeklypicture.png
}
```

You can change the weeklypicture.png in the database and it will change in the app as well.
Check [firebase](https://www.google.se/search?q=firebase&gws_rd=cr&ei=Lg2LWcyxFcHRwQL1jLmwAg) for simple examples.

Comment: He wants to control from the server @Vojb-

Comment: yeah , he can control it from the firebase server?

Comment: ohh ok that makes sense thanks